# Runtime Error VBS/VBA

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

This code was working perfectly until I tried to add error handling (for when the webquery in the VBA didn't pull back any data).  Now it still runs, but I get the following error:

```
Script: C:\Test\test.vbs
Line: 8
Char: 1
Error: Cannot access 'Test.xlsm'.
Code: 800A9C68
Source: Microsoft Excel
```

This is my VBScript, which essentially just calls my VBA inside of the .xlsm workbook

```vb
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
curDir = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")

Set myxlApplication = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
myxlApplication.Visible = False
Set myWorkBook = myxlApplication.Workbooks.Open( "C:\Test\Test.xlsm" ) 'Change to the actual workbook that has the Macro
myWorkBook.Application.Run "Module1.Mail_ActiveSheet" 'Change to the Module and Macro that contains your macro
myxlApplication.Quit
```

The following is my VBA code that refreshes the webquery, re-formats some small formatting errors then saves the sheet as .csv in the current directory.

```vb
Private Declare Function GetActiveWindow Lib "user32" () As Long

Sub Mail_ActiveSheet()
    ' Error Handling
    On Error GoTo Errhandler
    ' Refreshes webquery
    Application.Worksheets("Test").Range("A1").QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

    ' Enters Title Comments in Cell M2
    Range("$M$2").Value = "Notes"
    ' Enters formula in column M
    Range("$M$3").Formula = Range("G3") & (":") & Range("L3")

    Dim Lastrow As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Lastrow = Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("M3:M" & Lastrow).Formula = "=""TT""&G3&"":""&L3"
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    ' Replaces comma's with periods
    Cells.Replace What:=",", Replacement:=".", LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    ' Formats column H as text
    Range("E:E").NumberFormat = "General"
    Range("H:H").NumberFormat = "@"

    ' Fixes formatting adding leading zeros to site codes
    Columns("H").Replace What:="808", LookAt:=xlWhole, Replacement:="'0808", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns
    Columns("H").Replace What:="650", LookAt:=xlWhole, Replacement:="'65E1", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns
    Columns("H").Replace What:="941", LookAt:=xlWhole, Replacement:="'0941", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns
    Columns("H").Replace What:="17", LookAt:=xlWhole, Replacement:="'0017", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns
    Columns("H").Replace What:="168", LookAt:=xlWhole, Replacement:="'0168", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns
    Columns("H").Replace What:="420", LookAt:=xlWhole, Replacement:="'0420", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns
    Columns("H").Replace What:="535", LookAt:=xlWhole, Replacement:="'0535", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns
    Columns("H").Replace What:="560", LookAt:=xlWhole, Replacement:="'0560", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns
    Columns("H").Replace What:="572", LookAt:=xlWhole, Replacement:="'0572", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns
    Columns("H").Replace What:="575", LookAt:=xlWhole, Replacement:="'0575", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns
    Columns("H").Replace What:="750", LookAt:=xlWhole, Replacement:="'0750", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns
    Columns("H").Replace What:="760", LookAt:=xlWhole, Replacement:="'0760", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns
    Columns("H").Replace What:="815", LookAt:=xlWhole, Replacement:="'0815", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns
    Columns("H").Replace What:="822", LookAt:=xlWhole, Replacement:="'0822", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns
    Columns("H").Replace What:="823", LookAt:=xlWhole, Replacement:="'0823", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns
    Columns("H").Replace What:="824", LookAt:=xlWhole, Replacement:="'0824", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns
    Columns("H").Replace What:="886", LookAt:=xlWhole, Replacement:="'0886", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns

Lable1:
    Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim SaveToDirectory As String

    Dim CurrentWorkbook As String
    Dim CurrentFormat As Long

    CurrentWorkbook = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    CurrentFormat = ThisWorkbook.FileFormat
    ' Store current details for the workbook
    SaveToDirectory = "C:\Test\"
    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Sheets(WS.Name).Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveToDirectory & WS.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
        ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
        ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Next

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=CurrentWorkbook, FileFormat:=CurrentFormat
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    ' Temporarily turn alerts off to prevent the user being prompted
    '  about overwriting the original file.
    End

Errhandler:
    Sheet1.Cells.Clear
    Resume Label1 'Lable1 is placed before the place the workbook is saved
End Sub
```

The error handling that I was trying to do, was something along these lines:

```vb
'This was placed above the webquery portion of the script
On Error GoTo Errhandler
Errhandler:
    Sheet1.Cells.Clear
    Resume Label1 'Lable1 is placed before the place the workbook is saved
```

Comment: How many times have you opened the XLSM (invisibility) and not closed it before attempting to open it again? If you open Task Manager, how many Excel.exe entries do you have on the Processes tab?

Comment: I usually have 1 remaining open in task manager after I closed excel. Can't figure out what's causing it to stay open though.

Comment: Try set myxlApplication = Nothing at the end

Comment: It sounds as if you have an invisible Excel.Application that wasn't closed and this likely has the `C:\Test\Test.xlsm` file open within it. You are not going to be able to open it again until you get rid of that; probably by crashing it closed using Task Manager. I don't see where you are closing `ThisWorkbook`, just `ActiveWorkbook`.

Comment: Scratch that last comment I left.... Probably should get some more coffee at this point... Tried that at the end of the VBScript and no luck getting rid of the error.

Comment: As Jeeped said: kill all running Excel instances in Task Manager and start over. Also, where exactly did you place the error handler? Please show the code as-is.

Comment: Update: Re-added error-handler because I'll need to get it in there eventually. And was able to isolate the problem to the block of code that saves the work book (under "Lable1" block of code). If I comment out that entire block the script works without any errors, but doesn't save... I can't figure out why that block of code would give me errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, finally got it.... For some reason, if I split the portion of the VBA code in Excel that saves the workbook to a new macro I no longer get the error.

So I ended up with 3 Macros. The portion above Lable1, then Lable1 and another macro that calls both of those macros in the order they are supposed to run.

Also for the error handling, I was missing the Exit Sub command to stop it from executing when there is no error.

Thanks for all the help!